# AngularJS: Font Awesome Like Button not showing under ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a font awesome like button using ng-show on a boolean value of true or false.
Here is the code in my index

```
<p ng-controller="DivCtrl2" style="background-color:red"> 
         Here is red
<div ng-show="hasLikedUser == false" class="tab-item" ng-click="toggleLikeUserPage()">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: 2em; float:left; padding-left: 16px; margin-top:12px " ></i>
</div>

<div ng-show="hasLikedUser == true" class="tab-item" ng-click="toggleLikeUserPage()">
<i  class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size: 2em; float:left; padding-left: 16px; margin-top:12px " ></i>
</div>
    </p>
```

Here is the code in my controller file:

```
.controller('DivCtrl2', function($scope) {
 $scope.toggleLikeUserPage = function()
        {

            if($scope.hasLikedUser){
                $scope.hasLikedUser = false;
        alert("This is false");
            } else{
                $scope.hasLikedUser = true;
        alert("This is true");
            }

        }
```

Here is the plunk demo I have made
https://plnkr.co/edit/Zhxmmmypkypd95gXYrzx?p=preview
My challenge is that when I run the code the font icon does not appear. Please what am i getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your `ng-show` statements from `ng-show="hasLikedUser == false"` to `ng-show="!hasLikedUser"`, and from `ng-show="hasLikedUser == true"` to `ng-show="hasLikedUser"`. Your template will be as follows:

```
<div ng-show="!hasLikedUser" class="tab-item" ng-click="toggleLikeUserPage()">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: 2em; float:left; padding-left: 16px; margin-top:12px " ></i>
</div>

<div ng-show="hasLikedUser" class="tab-item" ng-click="toggleLikeUserPage()">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size: 2em; float:left; padding-left: 16px; margin-top:12px " ></i>
</div>
```

You do not need to test if `hasLikedUser` is equal to a boolean expression, since it *is a boolean expression*.

Answer (score 0):

Initially hasLikedUser isn't set so will be undefined so neither the == true or == false checks will pass.  Change your conditions to check just truthy or falsy:

```
<div ng-show="!hasLikedUser" class="tab-item" ng-click="toggleLikeUserPage()">
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: 2em; float:left; padding-left: 16px; margin-top:12px " ></i>
</div>

<div ng-show="hasLikedUser" class="tab-item" ng-click="toggleLikeUserPage()">
  <i  class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size: 2em; float:left; padding-left: 16px; margin-top:12px " ></i>
</div>
```

As undefined is one of the falsey values the first condition will pass and the first icon will be shown.